# Open the next html file in the directory

Tags: html, navigation

I am making a sort of "html app" which involves a very large number of seperate .html files. The 'app' is a sort of 'pro tips' thing, where on every page, is a life tip. I am wondering if there is a code for opening the next html file within the same directory, instead of changing the next tip's in each html file to open it.
Example:

`<a href="1.html">Next Tip</a>`

Then in the next tip's html file I would have to put:

`<a href="2.html">Next Tip</a>`

And so on:

`<a href="3.html">Next Tip</a>`

Sorry if I am not being clear enough.

Comment: Well, if it's numbered like that why don't you just iterate over it?

Comment: What (programming) language do you want to use? You going to have use server side script to read a directory or you can do it with JavaScript but that won't read a directory for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a client-side only solution this might work for your scenario. Give the a tag an id and add the script part to very page. It will parse your current filename, parses the number from it, adds one and buildsup the next url, replacing that value on your `a` tag

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- REMEMBER TO PUT THE ID ON IT -->
<a id="next" href="n.html">next</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and create a new file called `nav.js` in your folder and add this code to it:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a=document.getElementById('next'),
        l=document.location.href,
        s=Math.max(l.lastIndexOf('\\'),l.lastIndexOf('/')),
        d=l.indexOf('.'),
        f=l.substring(s+1,l.indexOf('.')),
        p=l.substring(0,s+1),
        e=l.substring(s+1+f.length, l.length),
        n=parseInt(f,10) + 1;
    if (a) {
       a.href= p + n.toString()+e;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks this one works great :D I don't have much experience with the other one in php, so thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could rename all the files into an ordered way, for example tip1.htm, tip2.htm, etc. with [Bulk Rename Utility](http://bulkrenameutility.co.uk) or [Ant Renamer](http://antp.be/software/renamer) if you don't want to get your hands dirty with lots of CMD and PowerShell. After that, add this php code to your main page:

```
<?php
$file="";
$counter=0;
$arr=array('tip','0','.htm');
function next_file()
{
    $counter=$counter+1;
    $arr[1]=streval($counter);
    include(join("", $arr));
}
?>
```

Then just call the next_file() function every time the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files 1.html, 2.html, etc. this will work.

On your html pages include a blank div (where you want the link to be):

```
<div id="link"></div>
```

Include a separate javascript file in the pages:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And then write this in that javascript file:

```
window.onload = function() {
var maxPages = 3;

var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var thenumber = filename.replace(".html", "");
thenumber++;
if (thenumber > maxPages) {
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="1.html">Next Tip</a>';
} else {
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="' + thenumber + '.html">Next Tip</a>';
}
}
```

Set `maxPages` so when you get to the end of all the tips, you will go back to the beginning.